# How to draw a SimpleWeightedGraph on a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jgrapht, jgraph

I have a SimpleWeightedGraph and I want to draw it on a JPanel in a JFrame.
Unfortunately nothing is drawn.

I read [this article](http://jgrapht.org/visualizations.html). They are using a `ListenableDirectedGraph` so I tried a `ListenableUndirectedGraph` with no success.

```
public class DisplayGraphForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public DisplayGraphForm(SimpleWeightedGraph g) {
       initComponents(); // graphPanel added to JFrame with BorderLayout (Center)

       JGraphModelAdapter adapter = new JGraphModelAdapter(g);

       JGraph jgraph = new JGraph(adapter);
       graphPanel.add(jgraph);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks that you're leaving some important details out of your question, and without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is hard to say where is the problem.

However, note that the sample you're trying to adopt is very old. `JGraph` has moved on to `JGraphX`. Consider the following sample that demonstrates the link of `JGraphT` and `JGraphX` using `JGraphXAdapter`.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.jgrapht.ListenableGraph;
import org.jgrapht.ext.JGraphXAdapter;
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultWeightedEdge;
import org.jgrapht.graph.ListenableDirectedWeightedGraph;
import com.mxgraph.layout.mxCircleLayout;
import com.mxgraph.layout.mxIGraphLayout;
import com.mxgraph.swing.mxGraphComponent;

public class DemoWeightedGraph {

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DemoGraph");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ListenableGraph<String, MyEdge> g = buildGraph();
        JGraphXAdapter<String, MyEdge> graphAdapter = 
                new JGraphXAdapter<String, MyEdge>(g);

        mxIGraphLayout layout = new mxCircleLayout(graphAdapter);
        layout.execute(graphAdapter.getDefaultParent());

        frame.add(new mxGraphComponent(graphAdapter));

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }

    public static class MyEdge extends DefaultWeightedEdge {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(getWeight());
        }
    }

    public static ListenableGraph<String, MyEdge> buildGraph() {
        ListenableDirectedWeightedGraph<String, MyEdge> g = 
            new ListenableDirectedWeightedGraph<String, MyEdge>(MyEdge.class);

        String x1 = "x1";
        String x2 = "x2";
        String x3 = "x3";

        g.addVertex(x1);
        g.addVertex(x2);
        g.addVertex(x3);

        MyEdge e = g.addEdge(x1, x2);
        g.setEdgeWeight(e, 1);
        e = g.addEdge(x2, x3);
        g.setEdgeWeight(e, 2);

        e = g.addEdge(x3, x1);
        g.setEdgeWeight(e, 3);

        return g;
    }
}
```

[image]

Note that `MyEdge` extends `DefaultWeightedEdge` to provide custom `toString()` that displays edge weight. A cleaner solution would be probably to override `mxGraph.convertValueToString`, examine content of cells and provide custom labels as needed. `toString` is a shortcut for the demo and also I noticed that `DefaultWeightedEdge.getWeight()` is protected, so the extension is needed anyway :)

Comment: Can you extend slightly the example to consider greater graphs (200+ nodes and edges) ? Or if you know a referenecs for zooming out, or something similar.